# Windows Phone 8 Decompile Appx From Binary

Tags: windows-phone

I lost my source code for a Win phone 8 app. 
I have the binary (appx) archive. 
My question is : is there any way to decompile my binary to get the source code ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rename your "binary" myfile.appx.zip and unzip it with your favorite tool.
There you should have your assemblies (.exe, .dll), and using a tool like Telerik's JustDecompile you can decompile the code.

It won't be 1:1 because you will see all the work the compiler has done for you (auto-properties, async/await, ...) but you should be able to extract the core of what you've done.

The only things that can't be recovered (as far as I know) are your XAML files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use: `makeappx unpack /p {path to the appx} /d {output dir}` in command line to extract the files from the `appx` then decompile the `.dll`